# Is the ABI part of the C standard?

Tags: c, abi

It seems to me that C libraries almost never have issues mixing libraries compiled with different versions or (sometimes) even different compilers, and that many languages seem to be able to interface with C libraries either directly or with minimal effort.

Is this all because the ABI is standard?

Comment: Try combining library built with softfp ABI with application built with hard-float ABI on ARM machines. You'll be surprized.

Comment: MinGW and MSVC compiles code often has trouble working together.  http://www.mingw.org/category/wiki/msvc  And the problem has been seen in plenty of other places too;  the standard advice is to build everything with the same toolchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ABI is defined by the Operatingsystem and/or the toolchain and is not defined by the standard. It defines for example how params are passed to a function call. What layout the stackframe has or how system calls are invoked.

The reason why most languages are able to interface with C libraries is most likely because most operating systems are (more or less) written in C, exposing C libraries as API and define a ABI based on that. And if a library written in a certain language wants to interface a specific OS, it has to be able to interface the ABI of this OS.

Comment: Accepted because this is the only answer that explains why a C interface seems to be universally accessible.

Answer (score 7):

ABIs are not codified in the language standard. You can get a copy of any of the C standard drafts to see it yourself.

And there's a good reason for ABIs not being in the standard. The standard cannot anyhow foresee all hardware and OSes for which C compilers can be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The ABI is most definitely not standard.  At least, not in the C standard.  Each operating system or tool chain specifies these things, but the language itself does not.  Try running a windows program on a Linux machine, for example.

Answer (score 1):

ABI is not a part of C standard. However, there had been efforts to standardize ABI. Quoting from "[Linux System Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009588.do)" :

> Although several attempts have been made at defining a single ABI for a given archi-
>   tecture across multiple operating systems (particularly for i386 on Unix systems), the
>   efforts have not met with much success. Instead, operating systems—Linux
>   included—tend to define their own ABIs however they see fit.